# Download txt with ';' delimiter and convert to .CSV with python

Tags: python, csv, tex

I have to download this .txt file: [Link](http://www.ceps.cz/_layouts/15/Ceps/_Pages/GraphData.aspx?mode=txt&from=1/1/2011%2012:00:00%20AM&to=1/2/2011%2011:59:59%20PM&hasinterval=True&sol=1&lang=ENG&agr=MI&fnc=AVG&ver=RT&)

Then I have to parse it to .csv and remove all header.

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work for me, this is my code:

```
import urllib
import csv

outfilename = "temp.txt"
csvfile = "data.csv" #open('data.csv', 'wb')
url_of_file = "http://www.ceps.cz/_layouts/15/Ceps/_Pages/GraphData.aspx?mode=txt&from=1/1/2011%2012:00:00%20AM&to=1/2/2011%2011:59:59%20PM&hasinterval=True&sol=1&lang=ENG&agr=MI&fnc=AVG&ver=RT&"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_of_file, outfilename) 


with open(outfilename, "rb") as infile, open(csvfile, 'wb') as outfile:
    in_txt = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ';')
    out_csv = csv.writer(outfile)
    out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

In this code I didn't do anything with header because even converting is not working yet.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, that this code doesn't work. You can try it in your IDE, it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Python code is not compiled. Your error has to be in your question. Everyone who reads it is not going to pull out their IDE and run your code.

Comment: This code doesn't work in the deafult Python console. So the IDE is irreveleant in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use this code for Python 2:

```
    import urllib
    import csv
    import urllib2

    outfilename = "temp.txt"
    csvfile = "data.csv" #open('data.csv', 'wb')
    url_of_file = "http://www.ceps.cz/_layouts/15/Ceps/_Pages/GraphData.aspx?mode=txt&from=1/1/2011%2012:00:00%20AM&to=1/2/2011%2011:59:59%20PM&hasinterval=True&sol=1&lang=ENG&agr=MI&fnc=AVG&ver=RT&"
    #urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_of_file, outfilename) 

    response = urllib2.urlopen(url_of_file)
    output = open(outfilename,'wb')
    output.write(response.read())
    output.close()

    with open(outfilename, "rb") as infile, open(csvfile, 'wb') as outfile:
        in_txt = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ';')
        out_csv = csv.writer(outfile)
        i = 0
        for row in in_txt:
            i +=1
            if i>3:
                out_csv.writerow(row)
```

Python 3:

```
    import urllib.request
    import csv

    outfilename = "temp.txt"
    csvfile = "data.csv"
    url_of_file = "http://www.ceps.cz/_layouts/15/Ceps/_Pages/GraphData.aspx?mode=txt&from=1/1/2011%2012:00:00%20AM&to=1/2/2011%2011:59:59%20PM&hasinterval=True&sol=1&lang=ENG&agr=MI&fnc=AVG&ver=RT&"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_of_file, outfilename) 

    with open(outfilename, encoding='utf-8') as infile, open(csvfile, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
            in_txt = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ';')
            out_csv = csv.writer(outfile)
            i = 0
            for row in in_txt:
                i +=1
                if i>3:
                    out_csv.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what should I do if it say:
ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'

Comment: By the way is says:
Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: I think you are using Python 3, I used Python 2.7, that's why this issue. If you can use, Python 2.7, that'd be good. I'll try to post another code that works with Python 3.

Which file you are talking about?

Comment: I'm using 3.0, sorry I didn't mentioned this. I would really appreciate if u could rewrite the code to run on 3.0

Comment: Please use the same code as yours, just import urllib.request and not simply urllib

also when u read the file, just use 'r' or encoding='utf-8', that should do

Comment: It's not working:
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Your soluiton is very close to my answer in my opinion. If you could update with 3.0 code it would be perfect :)

Comment: @Twi I've added the code with the modifications, works on my computer. should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `request` namespace in `urllib`.

Replace this line

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_of_file, outfilename)
```

With this

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url_of_file, outfilename)
```

**UPDATED**:

You need to import `urllib.request`, not just `urllib`.

Also, you need to open the files in text mode, not binary mode (which is 'rb', or 'wb').

```
import urllib.request
import csv

outfilename = "temp.txt"
csvfile = "data.csv" #open('data.csv', 'wb')
url_of_file = "http://www.ceps.cz/_layouts/15/Ceps/_Pages/GraphData.aspx?mode=txt&from=1/1/2011%2012:00:00%20AM&to=1/2/2011%2011:59:59%20PM&hasinterval=True&sol=1&lang=ENG&agr=MI&fnc=AVG&ver=RT&"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_of_file, outfilename)


with open(outfilename, "r") as infile, open(csvfile, 'w') as outfile:
    in_txt = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ';')
    out_csv = csv.writer(outfile)
    out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Comment: It has. The IDE doesn't show any error/warning on that. The problem is not here, but thanks.

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Spyder (Winpython 3.4)